# Gatsby Develop Failing using gatsby-plugin-sass

Tags: sass, gatsby, postcss, postcss-loader

After installing the gatsby-plugin-sass module:

When I try to run gatsby build, I get the following error:

```
 ERROR 

Unknown error from PostCSS plugin. Your current PostCSS version is 6.0.23, but autoprefixer uses 7.0.26. Perhaps this is the source of the error below.


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

Browser queries must be an array or string. Got object.

File: src/indexs.sass

failed Building development bundle - 9.200s
```

I have been working on a resolution to this for hours. I have tried:

- custom webpack rules in gatsby-node.js for sass files
- reading, re-reading, and re-re-reading the instruction on gatsby's site
- updating PostCSS using npm in every way I know how

So far, nothing has worked.

Why is it so complicated to get sass working with gatsby? When the documentation on gatsby's site makes it seem so easy?

Any suggestions what I can do to get this working?

in gatsby-node.js:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({
  stage,
  rules,
  loaders,
  plugins,
  actions,
}) => {
  // console.log('rules',rules)
  // console.log('rules.css',rules.css())
  // console.log('rules',rules.postcss())
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
          use: [
            // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
            'style-loader',
            // Translates CSS into CommonJS
            'css-loader',
            // Compiles Sass to CSS
            'sass-loader',

          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      plugins.define({
        __DEVELOPMENT__: stage === `develop` || stage === `develop-html`,
      }),
    ],
  })
}
```

---

In gatsby-config.js:

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
      options: {
        postCssPlugins: [require(`postcss-preset-env`)({ stage: 0 })],
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
```

---

the sass import line in gatsby-browser.js:

```
import "./src/indexs.sass"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sass` instead of `node-sass` saved my day.

remove `node-sass`

```
npm uninstall node-sass
or
yarn remove node-sass
```

and add `sass` aka `dart-sass`

```
npm install --save-dev sass
or
yarn add sass
```

then edit `gatsby-config.js`

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    options: {
      implementation: require("sass"),
  },
 },
]
```

now run `gatsby develop`

:)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party but hopefully this might help someone.
I have Sass setup and working with Gatsby without to much extra config required.

1. Install both `node-sass` and `gatsby-plugin-sass` via `npm`.

```
npm install --save node-sass gatsby-plugin-sass
```

2. Include `gatsby-plugin-sass` in your `gatsby-config.js` file in `plugins: []` as below with any other Gatsby plugins you maybe using.

```
module.exports = {
    siteMetadata: {
        title: `#`,
        description: `#`,
        author: `#`,
    },
    plugins: [
        `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    ],
}
```

3. Write your styles as `.sass` or `.scss` files and import your main `styles.scss` (or whatever you prefer to name it) either in your main `Layout.js` file or `gatsby-browser.js` file as below using the path to the location of your `styles.scss` file.

```
import "./src/styles/styles.scss"
```

I hope this works for you but if you have any other trouble add a comment and I'll try to reply back.

Comment: Thank you so much. Quick update: The docs say that node-sass is deprecated and that project should move to Dart Sass https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Comment: Yup, I have updated how I implement since this comment back in 2020. Gatsby has progressed rather fast so I'd say always check their docs. They are awesome docs!

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone chimes in on this to show how exactly to set up gatsbys sass plugin. I could not get it to work at all.

But I did find a workaround in my case:

1. I removed `gatsby-plugin-sass` from the plugins array in `gatsby-config.js`, turning it off (but I did not uninstall it using npm)
2. I installed `postcss-node-sass` and `postcss`
3. I added this info to the plugins array in gatsby-config.js:

```js
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
      options: {
        postCssPlugins: [
          require(`postcss-preset-env`)({ stage: 0 }),
          require(`postcss-node-sass`)(),
        ],
      },
    },
```

4. I added a custom rule for webpack in gatsby-node.js:

```js
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({
  stage,
  rules,
  loaders,
  plugins,
  actions,
}) => {
  // console.log('rules',rules)
  // console.log('rules.css',rules.css())
  // console.log('rules',rules.postcss())
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
          use: [
            // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
            'style-loader',
            // Translates CSS into CommonJS
            'css-loader',
            // Compiles Sass to CSS
            'sass-loader',

          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      plugins.define({
        __DEVELOPMENT__: stage === `develop` || stage === `develop-html`,
      }),
    ],
  })
}
```